# Is there a SQLI function that cycles through an array to see if any elements are in a MYSQL row?

Tags: php, mysqli, tags

I have a small SQL table.
There is a 'tags' column that has several words separated by a comma. 
Using PHP & MYSQLI I would like to take a **Search Value** and compare it's individual words with the individual words in the tag SQL 'tags' column.

It is a relatively small database. I can think of a way to do this where I create a seperate column for every tag. But I  would rather not. Only if that is the only option.

**Example SQL layout**,
*Table: Books*

"title" -- "author" -- "tags"

```
[Potter]-- [J.K.] -- [Wizards, WandsnShit,Magic]

[50 shades]-- [James] -- [Boobies, Sex]

[Ulysses]-- [Joyce] -- [WTF]
```

So far my direction has been:

```
//obtains searchValue from HTML
$searchValue=$_GET["searchValue"];

//turns the values individual words into an array
$proxy = $searchValue;
$tags = explode(" ", $proxy);

//This is where I need help
SELECT * FROM books WHERE tags CONTAINS (cycle through 'tags' array)
```

If all works correctly, typing "**Gandalf is a wizard**" should return the book "**Potter**".
Because "**Wizard**" is a tag of "**Potter**" book.

Also while I'm at it. Does the PHP  function "explode" alter the original string or create a copy string an alter that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The explode will make a copy from the original. But why you do not take a php loop?

Comment: What you did is turned a nice and awesome database into a big, glorified text file. Why would you store tags in a **column**? You just shot yourself in the foot. Our ancestor developers created relational databases so we **don't have to do** what you did. Long story short, you don't create a column, you don't compare to a column. You create **another table** or even two tables. One table stores tags, another table stores your books and the third table links books to tags. This is how we deal with data modelling. And if you do that, your problem simply goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad design. Let's search on the net for database normalization.

In your book table should be a unique id (primary key, int, not null, auto increment) field. After that, you need to create a relation table, what has the tags.

For example:

**Book table:**

```
id
name
author
```

**Tags table**

```
id
book_id
tag
```

After that you can use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books"
    . " INNER JOIN tags ON tags.book_id = books.id"
    . " WHERE tags.tag = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["searchValue"]);
```

Or you can use `LIKE` keyword.

**Note:**

I am always wondering, why a lot of developer create 2 variable for nothing?

```
$searchValue=$_GET["searchValue"];
//turns the values individual words into an array
$proxy = $searchValue;
$tags = explode(" ", $proxy);
```

instead: `$tags = explode(" ", $_GET["searchValue");`

Comment: Change to `WHERE tags.tag` to stop confusion and `INNER JOIN`